# What's at the other end of the Forbidden Forest?

Tags: harry-potter

The Forbidden Forest is unquestionably massive. As the title implies, what's at the other end of the forest  ? Surely the forest must come to an end somewhere - so what exists beyond the forest  ?

Comment: My money is on a Forbidden Starbucks.

Comment: Or a Forbidden Gift Shoppe

Comment: Who visits the Forbidden Starbucks  ? Aragog  ? I didn't know acromantulas have a taste for caffeine lol

Comment: @TheMadHatter Centaurs - it helps them stay up late for stargazing